# bootstrap pages did not have any effects in python project of PyCharm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask

I use PyCharm create web project in python and flask.

The html pages using bootstrap4 had not any effects and I use bootstrap as follow:
the root path of my project is:flask-wx
the bootstrap package path is: flask-wx/templates/bootstrap, and the index.html was locate in: flask-wx/templates/index.html.

and i add the code on the header of html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css">

<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Title</title>
```

But when I run this project, the index has not any effects of bootstrap, I do not know what problem it have.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are new to stack overflow, so welcome.

You should put all your html files in `templates` folder and all other css, js files in `static` folder.
So your bootstrap files should be in `flask-wx/static/bootstrap`

You serve them from yout html template with `url_for` as followed:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css') }}">

<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

<title>Title</title>
```

Comment: thanks bro！！！   u save my life  ：D，i fix this issue follow your suggestion. Yes, i am the fresh man in html, i think that i could get help in stackflow, now i am right. thanks u again